# setsearch in GP/PARI: testing cubic residues

Tags: search, pari-gp, finite-field

I am trying to write a program in GP/PARI which given a finite field (in this example, I will use the degree 2 field of 9 elements over p=3), computes the cube of all elements and stores it in a list (I understand this is very inefficient). Then, I want to evaluate some functions at points in the same field and test whether it is in this list (whether it is a cubic residue). I am attempting to accomplish this with lists in GP/PARI and then using setsearch on it.

I begin by first defining my irreducible polynomial mod 3. I then run through all the elements in my 9 element field cubing them and storing it in a list, which is realized as a quotient of this polynomial ring (double mods). Once I have this list, I am now running into trouble with setsearch. First of all, it seems the list is storing it in terms of double mods. Visually very ugly, but I don't mind as long as it can do the computations. However, it seems that it cannot. For example, 0 should be in the list, but testing it with setsearch returns false. I guess the reason is that in the list, 0 is stored as `Mod(Mod(0,3),rpoly)`

and indeed, (see below), that does seem to be the case. However, something even worse is happening. 
>

```
(15:45) gp > rpoly=Mod(1,3)*(x^2-x-1);
(15:45) gp > polisirreducible(rpoly)
%2 = 1
(15:45) gp > cubic=listcreate(9);
(15:45) gp > for(a=0,2,for(b=0,2,listput(cubic,Mod(Mod(1,3)*(a*x+b)^3,rpoly))))
(15:46) gp > cubic
%5 = List([Mod(Mod(0, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(1, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(2, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(1, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(2, 3)*x, Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(1, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(1, 3)*x, Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3)), Mod(Mod(1, 3)*x + Mod(1, 3), Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(2, 3)*x + Mod(2, 3))])
(15:46) gp > setsearch(cubic,Mod(Mod(0,3),rpoly))
%6 = 0
(15:47) gp > setsearch(cubic,Mod(Mod(0,3)*x+Mod(0,3),rpoly))
%7 = 1
```

So it seems that not only is it refusing to acknowledge that 0 is in the list, but even other forms of 0 that one would naturally encounter when running through the field isn't working: it specifically wants %7

Why is this happening? More importantly, is there any way to fix this to accomplish my aims here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know gp, but can you verify that your list of cubics is correct? I get the following.

```
((0x + 0)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 0 = {0,0}
((0x + 1)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 1 = {0,1}
((0x + 2)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 2 = {0,2}
((1x + 0)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 1 = {2,1}
((1x + 1)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 2 = {2,2}
((1x + 2)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 0 = {2,0}
((2x + 0)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 2 = {1,2}
((2x + 1)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 0 = {1,0}
((2x + 2)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 1 = {1,1}
```

All 8 non-zero elements can be considered to be powers of 1x + 0:

```
((1x + 0)^0) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 1 = {0,1}
((1x + 0)^1) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 0 = {1,0}
((1x + 0)^2) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 1 = {1,1}
((1x + 0)^3) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 1 = {2,1}
((1x + 0)^4) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 2 = {0,2}
((1x + 0)^5) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 0 = {2,0}
((1x + 0)^6) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 2x + 2 = {2,2}
((1x + 0)^7) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 1x + 2 = {1,2}
((1x + 0)^8) mod (x^2 - 1x - 1) = 0x + 1 = {0,1} (sequence repeats)
```

So multiply or exponentiation could be implemented using the equivalent of log and antilog:

```
((2x + 2)^3) => ((1x + 0)^6)^3 => ((1x + 0)^(18 mod 8)) => (1x + 0)^2 => 1x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with `setsearch`:

1. it will only work with a *sorted* list (with respect to the internal universal comparison function `cmp`); so you must use `listsort(~cubic)`, which sorts your list in place (with respect to `cmp`).
2. the comparison function `cmp` makes little mathematical sense, in particular it doesn't test for mathematical equality:

```
    ? cmp(Mod(0, 2), 0)
    %1 = 0
```

So you want to search for an element in the very same form it was input.

The simplest way to achieve this (and to improve on the "very ugly" double polmod printing) is to use the `t_FFELT` type (finite field element) as follows: in the code below `t` represents `Mod(x, rpoly)`

```
? rpoly = Mod(1,3)*(x^2-x-1); t = ffgen(rpoly, 't); cubic = List();
? for(a=0,2, for(b=0,2, listput(cubic, a*t + b)))
? cubic \\ nicer looking
%3 = List([0, 1, 2, t, t + 1, t + 2, 2*t, 2*t + 1, 2*t + 2])
? listsort(~cubic)
? cubic \\ not how the order changed !
%5 = List([0, 1, 2, t, 2*t, t + 1, 2*t + 1, t + 2, 2*t + 2])
? setsearch(cubic, 0*t)
%6 = 1
? setsearch(cubic, 0) \\ expected
%7 = 0
```

The final result is expected because the integer `0` is not the finite field element `0*t`. Even though `gp` would consider them equal (the `==` operator) they are not *identical* (the `===` operator):

```
? 0 == 0 * t
%8 = 1
? 0 === 0 * t
%9 = 0
```